# jquery spring mvc html in javascript code

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I have two tabs like the one shown below. 
User selects the checkbox which he want to edit and the next tab shows the field for editing the field. 
My first tab is loaded using jquery load function. For preparing the second tab I am using direct jquery code like..
("#tab2").append(username[i] + ".....");

I am worried that if I have to change tab2 page structure in the future then it will be very difficult to modify.
A friend gave me a suggestion that instead of appending html in javascript, load the tab2 using ajax. He meant to write the design in tab2.jsp and when next button is triggered tab2.jsp page will be loaded.
With his solution the problem is if user goes back to tab1 and edit the fields and click on next then tab2.jsp will be loaded again which means sending request to server again.

What do you think is the better way? give me some suggestion if any

[image: first page]

[image: second page]